# Firebase Analytics in multi module app — how to?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I have app with lots of modules. They look like this:

```
analytics // com.company.app.analytics – library module with analytics-related stuff
```

This library module contains `Analytics` object, which is responsible to send analytics events to Firebase and other systems.

```
ads // com.company.app.ads
```

`ads` library module is responsible for ads, has `analytics` module in dependencies and uses `Analytics` object to report some events.

// etc

```
app // com.company.app
```

This is the main module. It depends on both `analytics` and `ads`, and uses `Analytics` to report some events too.

So, as you can see, I can not move analytics logic (= `Analytics` object) to `app` module, because many modules want to use `Analytics` too.

How I set up the analytics:

1. Created app in Firebase console. Package name = `app` package name = `com.company.app` (it's not real package name, obviously I've changed it in this question)
2. Added `google-services.json` to `app`.
3. Added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the bottom of `app/build.gradle`.
4. Added dependency `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'` to `analytics/build.gradle`.
5. Re-installed app multiple times.
6. Reported some events to Firebase.

Current result:

**Nothing**. There is absolutely nothing in Firebase Console, it even does not see that I've finished the set up. No events in DebugView too.

However, I see lots of Firebase-related logs in the logcat, like:

```
Event recorded: Event{appId='package_here', name='banner_shown', params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=app, _r=1, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-6820243536992227035, _dbg=1}]}
12-29 18:20:22.018 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 500
12-29 18:20:22.019 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
12-29 18:20:22.020 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Scheduling upload with DelayedRunnable
12-29 18:20:22.020 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
12-29 18:20:22.020 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 500
12-29 18:20:22.021 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Background event processing time, ms: 11
12-29 18:20:22.522 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
12-29 18:20:22.523 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Starting upload from DelayedRunnable
12-29 18:20:22.528 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Checking account type status for ad personalization signals
12-29 18:20:22.537 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Saving bundle, size: 489
12-29 18:20:22.544 D/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 506
<-- Removed data output -->
12-29 18:20:22.549 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: package_here, 549, 
12-29 18:20:22.549 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: false, true, false
12-29 18:20:22.551 V/FA-SVC  ( 3045): Uploading data. size: 501
```

So, what's wrong with this set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems that I needed just to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'` to `app/build.gradle` too, not only to `analytics/build.gradle`.

Now it works.